# Andengine HUD OnscreenController

Tags: andengine, hud

Can anyone please tel me how to make a Analog onscreencontroller follow the screen? I used the code to make it a HUD but the knob doesn't respond to my touch,please help!

Comment: might help if you show us your code

Answer (score 0):

You might be attaching the controller to the scene. That is the reason the knob is not working.

what you should do is set the controller as child scene to your scene

```
setChildScene(AnalogOnScreenControl);
```

Now it will work.